# How to deploy Maximo Anywhere app as a new app version?

Tags: version, ibm-mobilefirst, maximo

I'm following IBM documentation in order to add barcode enabled in WorkExecution. After changing the property barcode.enabled to true and build/deploy app it works fine.

My question is : it's written 
"When you activate bar code scans, the updated app **must be deployed as a new app version**. Users must download and install the new app version from the server"

Does someone knows **how to change app version** ?? **or where** ? I search in every file in MaximoAnywhere project, every properties files, and i can't find nothing ...

Thanks

Comment: No links to whatever guide you are following, not mentioning what is your worklight version, not supplying any code or sample project, not supplying proper steps to to recreate. What exactly do you want help with here?

Comment: Sorry for missing informations, it's first time I post here .. The documentation i follow is here :
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPJLC_7.5.0/com.ibm.si.mpl.doc_7.5.0/configure/t_activate_bar_code.html?lang=en
Worklight version is, as recommanded by IBM for Maximo Anywhere, 5.0.6

Comment: This is how you download the new version to the mobile device after you have deployed the revised application it to the server: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPJLC_7.5.0/com.ibm.si.mpl.doc_7.5.0/build_deploy/t_install_apps_mobile_devices.html?lang=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app version is located in the application-descriptor.xml file of your Worklight application, as an attribute in the relevant `environment` element.
For example:

```
<iphone bundleId="com.myApp" version="1.0">
        <worklightSettings include="false"/>
        <security>
            <encryptWebResources enabled="false"/>
            <testWebResourcesChecksum enabled="false" ignoreFileExtensions="png, jpg, jpeg, gif, mp4, mp3"/>
        </security>
</iphone>
```

Note the `version="1.0"` attribute.

This attribute is explained in [The application descriptor](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_the_application_descriptor.html) user documentation topic:

> For mobile apps, the version is shown to users who download the app
>   from the app store or market.

Comment: Thank you, I finally found it in /MaximoAnywhere/platform/mobile/releng/resources/baseline/MaximoAnywhereProjectApp/application-descriptor.xml
IBM uses worklight for this project but the project structure isn't the same

Comment: @Atharaxie, if this answer helped you resolve your problem, please mark it as Answered.